# How to handle firewall inactivity timeout to batch database during long running tasklet?

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have a long running tasklet that takes hours to complete. There is a firewall between the box that  the batch job is running on and the batch database. The inactivity timeout on that firewall is two hours and our network team is unwilling to change that. So when the long running tasklet completes and Spring Batch goes to update the database with the status it fails because the firewall has already severed the connection due to inactivity. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here is my DataSource:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin@db_url" />
    <property name="username" value="username" />
    <property name="password" value="password" />
</bean>
```

Some more background information. This tasklet doesn't use this db connection. Only Spring Batch is using it. The tasklet job is to monitor a queue and complete to the next step once the queue is empty. This queue draining is what can take hours.

**UPDATE:** I tried adding the Oracle TCP keep alive but it still timed out.

```
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION=(ENABLE=BROKEN)(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=hostname)(PORT=port)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=sidname)))" />
```

Thanks.
Brian

Comment: There are a number of options I can propose depending on how you're getting connections in the first place.  If you update your question with your `DataSource` configuration (aka what connection pool you're using), we can go from there.

Comment: @MichaelMinella Thanks Michael. I have updated the original post with the DataSource. If you need more information please let me know.

Comment: Using Oracle, you should be able to configure the driver to use TCP keepalive so that it will keep some traffic going over the connection even when it's just waiting.  I couldn't find a straight forward example otherwise, I'd post it as an actual answer.

Comment: @MichaelMinella I tried adding the TCP keep alive but it still timed out. I updated my original post.

Comment: You may want to talk to your network administrator to find out, exactly, what they are seeing that causes it to be cut.  Is it really 2 hours of inactivity or is it just holding a connection for 2 hours, regardless of traffic (some firewalls don't like long running connections, period).  Once they let you know what is needed to keep the firewall from cutting the connect, we may be able to help further.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you really need a transaction for your tasklet, but in my case I was able to solve the issue by defining the transaction attribute:

```
@Bean
public Step myStep(StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory, MyTasklet myTasklet) {
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("myStep").tasklet(myTasklet).transactionAttribute(new DefaultTransactionAttribute(TransactionAttribute.PROPAGATION_NEVER)).build();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I have already tried that and it didn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to kill the long running jobs, then there 2 ways:

1. JobInterruptionPolicy
2. CommandLineRunner

We can kill the job programatically using JobInterruptedPolicy or manually using CommandLineRunner by exceuting command to STOP.

**JobInterruptionPolicy**

1. Use **JobOperator**.**stop** the job

   ```
    SimpleJobOperator jobOperator = new SimpleJobOperator();
    jobOperator.setJobRepository(jobRepository);
    jobOperator.setJobLauncher(jobLauncher);
    jobOperator.setJobExplorer(jobExplorer);
    jobOperator.setJobRegistry(jobRegistry);
    //If you know job execution id that you want to stop the job
    jobOperator.stop(exceutionId);
   ```
2. You can simply use **JobExceution.stop()** method if you have jobExceution object.

Above both the method worked for me successfully.

BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION table of Spring batch

Batch status:  STOPPED
ExitStatus: STOPPED